# How can I reference a parent and remove the parent element in an RSS XML through LXML in Python?

Tags: python, xml, rss, lxml

I've been having trouble cracking this one. I have an RSS feed in the form of an XML file. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>My RSS Feed</title>
        <link href="https://www.examplefeedurl.com">Feed</link>
        <description></description>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>
            <guid></guid>
            <pubDate></pubDate>
            <author/>
            <title>Title of the item</title>
            <link href="https://example.com" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
            <description>
            <![CDATA[<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">View Example</a>]]>
            </description>
            <description>
            <![CDATA[<p>This actually contains a bunch of text I want to work with. If this text contains certain strings, I want to get rid of the whole item.</p>]]>
            </description>
        </item>
        <item>...</item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

My objective is to check if the second description tag contains certain strings. If it does contain that string, I'd like to completely remove it. Currently in my code I have this:

```
doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(testString)
found = doc.findall('channel/item/description')


for desc in found:
    if "FORBIDDENSTRING" in desc.text:
        desc.getparent().remove(desc)
```

And it removes just the second description tag which makes sense but I want the whole **item** gone.
I don't know how I can get a hold on the 'item' element if I only have the 'desc' reference.

I've tried googling aswell as searching on here but the situations I see just want to remove the tag like I'm doing now, weirdly I haven't stumbled upon sample code that wants to get rid of the entire parent object.
Any pointers towards documentation/tutorials or help is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of XSLT, but another option is to just select the `item` instead of the `description` (select the element you want to delete; not its child).

Also, if you use `xpath()`, you can put the check for the forbidden string directly in the xpath predicate.

Example...

```
from lxml import etree

testString = """
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>My RSS Feed</title>
        <link href="https://www.examplefeedurl.com">Feed</link>
        <description></description>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>
            <guid></guid>
            <pubDate></pubDate>
            <author/>
            <title>Title of the item</title>
            <link href="https://example.com" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
            <description>
            <![CDATA[<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">View Example</a>]]>
            </description>
            <description>
            <![CDATA[<p>This actually contains a bunch of text I want to work with. If this text contains certain strings, I want to get rid of the whole item.</p>]]>
            </description>
        </item>
        <item>...</item>
    </channel>
</rss>
"""

forbidden_string = "I want to get rid of the whole item"

parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
doc = etree.fromstring(testString, parser=parser)
found = doc.xpath('.//channel/item[description[contains(.,"{}")]]'.format(forbidden_string))

for item in found:
    item.getparent().remove(item)

print(etree.tostring(doc, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
```

this prints...

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>My RSS Feed</title>
        <link href="https://www.examplefeedurl.com">Feed</link>
        <description/>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: I had to some more logic with the text within the description tag except for checking for a forbidden string.
But your tip to use the item element got me on the right track, I used the item element, got the ChildElementIterator out that, used my logic and I could call back to item to remove it like in your example!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files such as removing nodes conditionally by value. Python's `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts and even pass a parameter from Python script to XSLT (not unlike passing parameters in SQL!). In this way, you avoid any `for` loops or `if` logic or rebuilding tree at application layer.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="description"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- VALUE TO BE PASSED INTO FROM PYTHON -->
  <xsl:param name="search_string" />       

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- KEEP ONLY item NODES THAT DO NOT CONTAIN $search_string -->
  <xsl:template match="channel">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item[not(contains(description[2], $search_string))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** *(for demo, below runs two searches using posted sample)*

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = et.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('XSLT_String.xsl')

# CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    

# RUN TRANSFORMATION WITH PARAM
n = et.XSLT.strparam('FORBIDDENSTRING')
result = transform(doc, search_string=n)

print(result)
# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <rss version="2.0">
#   <channel>
#     <item>...</item>
#     <item>...</item>
#     <item>...</item>
#     <item>
#       <guid/>
#       <pubDate/>
#       <author/>
#       <title>Title of the item</title>
#       <link href="https://example.com" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
#       <description><![CDATA[<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">View Example</a>]]></description>
#       <description><![CDATA[<p>This actually contains a bunch of text I want to work with. If this text contains certain strings, I want to get rid of the whole item.</p>]]></description>
#     </item>
#     <item>...</item>
#   </channel>
# </rss>

# RUN TRANSFORMATION WITH PARAM
n = et.XSLT.strparam('bunch of text')
result = transform(doc, search_string=n)

print(result)    
# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <rss version="2.0">
#   <channel>
#     <item>...</item>
#     <item>...</item>
#     <item>...</item>
#     <item>...</item>
#   </channel>
# </rss>

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Comment: Since you're only applying templates to `item` in the `channel` context, you're losing all of the other children of `channel` (like `title`, `description`, and `link`). What I would do is remove the template matching channel and add a template matching `item`. Since you can't reference a param/variable in a match pattern in XSLT 1.0, I'd add an xsl:if test with `not(description[contains(.,$search_string)])` (not testing the position of `description`) and if it's true, output the `item` (xsl:copy w/xsl:apply-templates to keep it push style).